# How to write a boolean value to peripheral device (PSoC BLE) from central device (iPhone 7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

I am very new at BLE implementations, so bear with me.  I am using Xcode 9.3, iOS version 11.3, and a PSoC 4200 BLE device.

I've got a custom circuit attached to the PSoC module that outputs a voltage to be sent via uint32 data packets to my iOS application.  My next step is to be able to create a `UIButton` object (just an on/off for now) and pass it's state back to the PSoC.

Forgetting the software used to setup the PSoC (Cypress's PSoC Creator 4.0 just fyi), I would like to know which delegate method/methods to use in Xcode to get this to work...my best guess is `peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests:` in the `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` protocol.  If I can only write back to the peripheral once the characteristic is read by the central, then I can use the last 8 bits of the uint32 voltage packet for the time being, if that's what the process requires. If it's better to create a new uint8 or boolean packet instead, and just use that as a write characteristic without intervening with the uint32, then I can do that too.

I have no transmission time requirements or energy consumption concerns as of now...I just need to get that boolean sent to the PSoC.

Any help at all will be much appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE:
after `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:` gets called, I call `[self getTransducerData:characteristic withPeripheral:peripheral error:error];`

Here is what happens in that method (I have added what I think is the appropriate way to use `writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:`)

```
- (void)getTransducerData:(CBCharacteristic*)characteristic withPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral
                error:(NSError*)error {
    NSData* data = [characteristic value];
    const uint8_t *reportData = [data bytes];
    uint32_t v0 = (uint32_t)reportData[0];
    uint32_t v1 = (uint32_t)reportData[1] << 8;
    uint32_t v2 = (uint32_t)reportData[2] << 16;
    //uint32_t v3 = (uint32_t)reportData[3] << 24;

    int32_t voltage = v0 | v1 | v2; //| v3;

    if ((characteristic.value) || !error) {

        /* _captureOn is the boolean value after my UIButton object receives a touch.  
           On and Off.  
           If it's on, notify the peripheral with the last 8 bits of the uint32_t characteristic with 0x01.*/
        if (_captureOn) {
            uint8_t temp[4];
            temp[0] = v0;
            temp[1] = v1;
            temp[2] = v2;
            temp[3] = 0x01;
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:temp length:4 freeWhenDone:YES];
            [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
        }

        self.transducerValue = voltage;
        self.realVoltage = voltage/1000000.0;

        //self.levelView.value = self.realVoltage;

        if (self.realVoltage <= _originalHigh && self.realVoltage >= _originalLow) {
            self.testerVoltage = self.realVoltage;
            self.middleTachometer.currentLevel = (float)self.realVoltage;
            self.transducerPosition.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3lf V", self.realVoltage];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt to write data?  You can't write a bool as such. You will just need to send an 8 bit byte and decide what is your convention for true/false (e.g. 0 = false, anything else is true). You should use a different characteristic for your bool.

Comment: I ended up using that [3] element to store either 0x00 or 0x01...when I call the `writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:` method, and evaluated it's effect in my Cypress BLE software, I realized that, unless I manipulated that incoming data via that software, it would just run a Write request sequence but not do anything.  I decided to use that trigger as a means to mimic an on/off switch.  Not at all wise, and certainly not the best solution (I will try to work in your suggestion of 2 characteristics when I become more familiar with the process.)